# How do I inspect the power-regulator of a Mac?

Tags: battery, power

As a tangent to:
[Can connecting 2 external monitors to a macbook pro damage it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413070/can-connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-macbook-pro-damage-it)

How does one get visibility into which power-source the Mac is running with? Are any detailed stats available underneath the hood?

Unrelated context: My MBP 16" 2020 is in the shop with a bad-battery. When my MBP chose the weaker power-source, combined with the failing battery, would cause OSX to go into preservation mode (fire the fans, dump ram to disk etc).  While I'd love to say that I've plugged things in the correct order, being able to verify cabling is also important.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

[iStat Menus 3](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) can get the wattage readings from some sensor, along with volt and amp stats. [This thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16102/how-to-retrieve-current-wattage-info-on-os-x) explains all options in detail.